# Removing first character in text if it begins with a certain character for specific columns only - Google App Script (Spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am really new to Google Apps Script and JavaScript in general, so apologies if I don't elaborate the best.

So I have a two columns that values start with either an "=" ex. =yfes83749== right now google sheets is reading this as a formula. I want to remove the "=" sign in the beginning only.

"+" ex. "+grocery+movies+bank" at the very minimum I'd like to remove the first "+" in cell values that begin with the "+"

"&" ex. "&url_utm_content&url_" I would just like to remove the first "&" in these cell values.

I have used the below scripts but I am having issues.

```
 function searchreplace() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange('BL:BL');
 var values = range.getValues();
 var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder("=").matchFormulaText(true);
 textFinder.replaceAllWith('..');
 }
```

^^^ the above worked to replace the "=" but it replaced all "=" signs in the entire sheet

i've also tried this which partially worked but once again replaced all instances

```
function replaceALL() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange('BL:BL');
var rule =SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
sheet.createTextFinder('+').replaceAllWith("") ||sheet.createTextFinder('%')
```

.replaceAllWith("" + "") || sheet.createTextFinder("&") .replaceAllWith(" ") ||
sheet.createTextFinder("==") .replaceAllWith("")
}

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: also and videos or resources you can recommend I watch/read would be super helpful as well, thanks again (:

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: See linked duplicate  at the top. `range.createTextFinder` instead of `sheet.createTextFinder`

Comment: @TheMaster that only solves part of my question how do I only replace the first instance of the symbols mentioned above in a cell. Example “+call+Email+text” I only want to remove the first + sign

Comment: Regex: `^+` refers to a `+` as the first letter. Also switch on `useRegularExpressions(true)`

Comment: Try it in the Google sheets find and replace user interface first. Also, see [regex wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).